# Error 310170 occured Property Node(arg 1) in Simulation Trace Environment

Tags: linux, embedded, labview

We tried to work out our code in LabView 2018 and tried to run it in Cybersim but this error is popping up. Any recommendation to improve the same will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without code snippets it will be not possible to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

310170 means  "The Ethercat is busy" https://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/372983F-01/lvrobogsm/robo_error_codes/

Without any code it's hard to help more.